# Non linear effect in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Suppose I want to study the non linear ODE

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x) + a f^2(x) + b f(x) + c=0$

I know the solution for $a=0$ and I know $a$ is a small parameter. How can I study the effect of the non linear term?

Comment: My answer from before had an error. (I did not take into account that $f_0$ was a solution for a specific $a = 0$). I have updated the answer with the new calculations. Hopefully, they are correct.

Comment: Thank you, to be honest I did not go through the detailed derivation, but I am very happy with the general scheme.
Thanks again

Comment: Ok I get the same result. Unfortunately the ODE to be derived to find $f_a$ is non-homogeneous with non-constant coefficients...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Though I do not have an exact formal reasoning for that, $maybe$ you could disregard the $\Delta a$ in the equation for $f_a$? That would make it nonhomogeneous with constant coefficients. You could possibly check how legitimate this step is by drawing some numeric solutions. Intuitively, I feel that since the equation is linear, and $\Delta a$ is small, it may not change things too drastically.

Comment: I had the same though. I'll let you know my results.
Cheers

Comment: Good news for me, I think you made a little mistake. If you track more carefully the neglected terms $O(\Delta a^n)$ you will see that the problematic term $\Delta a f_0 f_a$ disappears.

Comment: Okay, great. I'll see if I can find it and fix it. In any case, this is great news, since the $\Delta a$ in the equation was bothering me immensely. It doesn't seem right that the value of $\Delta a$ should affect $f_a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be quite interesting. What is written below is not 100% rigorous, and I would be happy for someone to verify my thoughts on the matter.

Nonetheless, this seems a nice way to possibly approximate and study your solution.

### EDIT:

The answer as it was written and accepted (In the grey box) had an error. I am adding the updated version. I am not deleting yet the original version (since it was the one to be accepted), until it this action is okayed by at least the author of the post, or one of the "moderators" here.

### New Answer

As before, let us denote $f = f(t,a)$ the solution to our equation. Let us assume you have arrived at a solution for some specific $a_0$, call this solution $f_0 = f(t,a_0)$, and now you are interested in approximating the solution $f$ at $a = a_0 + \Delta a$, where $\Delta a$ is small. In your case, $a_0 = 0$, we'll substitute this later.

Now, same as before, we denote $f_a = \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \right|_{a = a_0} f(t,a)$, and expanding into Taylor series and dropping the second-order terms, we can write $f = f_0 + \Delta af_a$.

$f$ is a solution to:

$$
f'' + af^2 + bf + c = 0
$$

Substitute all written above into the equation:

$$
(f_0 + \Delta a f_a)'' + (a_0+ \Delta a)(f_0 + \Delta a f_a)^2 + b(f_0 + \Delta a f_a) + c = 0
$$

Now we open the square, and rearrange the terms. We get
$$
(f_0'' + a_0 f_0^2 + b f_0 + c) + (\Delta a f_a'' + 2a_0 \Delta a f_0 f_a + a_0 \Delta a^2 f_a^2 + \Delta a f_0^2 + 2\Delta a^2 f_0 f_a + b \Delta a f_a) + O(\Delta a^3) = 0
$$

The contents of the first brackets vanish since $f_0$ is a solution for $a_0$. The rest we divide by $\Delta a$. $O(\Delta a^3)$ becomes $O(\Delta a^2)$, and we disregard it, since we have already agreed to drop second-order terms. We are left with:

$$
f_a'' + 2a_0f_0 f_a + a_0 \Delta a f_a^2 + f_0^2 + 2\Delta a f_0 f_a + bf_a = 0
$$

Now, we substitute that in our case $a_0 = 0$, and $a = a_0 + \Delta a = \Delta a$, and we have an equation for $f_a$:

$$
f_a'' + f_0^2 + 2\Delta a f_0 f_a + bf_a = 0
$$

Or

$$
f_a'' + (2\Delta a f_0 + b)f_a + f_0^2 = 0
$$

Which is a linear ODE, and $f = f_0 + a f_a$ (Up to second-order terms).

### Old Answer

> Let us think of $f = f(t,a)$ the solution to your equation. Then we
>   can write, using Taylor expansion (since $a$ is small):
>
> $$ f(t,a) = f(t,0) + a \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial a}
>  \right|_{a=0} f(t,a) + O(a^2) $$
>
> So if we define $f = f(t,a)$, $f_0 = f(t,0)$, and $f_a = \left.
> > \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \right|_{a=0} f(t,a)$, and we drop the
>   second-order remainder, we can write:
>
> $$ f = f_0 + af_a $$
>
> But $f$ is a solution to your ODE. So we plug this relation inside:
>
> $$ (f_0 + af_a)'' + a(f_0 + af_a)^2 + b(f_0 + af_a) + c = 0 $$ We open
>    the square, and rearrange the terms: $$ (f_0'' + af_0^2 + bf_0 + c) +
>  (af_a'' + 2a^2f_0f_a + baf_a) + O(a^3) = 0 $$
>
> Now, $f_0$ is a solution as well, so the content of the first brackets
>   vanishes. The rest, we divide by $a$, and disregard the $O(a^3)$,
>   since after the division it will become $O(a^2)$, and we have already
>   agreed to disregard teh second-order terms.
>
> We are left with an equation for $f_a$:
>
> $$ f_a'' + (2af_0)f_a + bf_a = 0 $$
>
> Since $f_0$ is known, this is a linear ODE, and if you find its
>   solution, you can affroximate $f$, as before $f = f_0 + af_a$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $f'$ to yield a integrable equation. After it depends on $f$ if you can do the last integral.

$\textbf{Edit:}$

$$
f'' f' + \left[af^2+bf + c\right]f' = f'\dfrac{d}{dx}f' + \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{3}af^3 + \frac{1}{2}bf^2+cf\right] = 0
$$
now we can re-write the last but one equation as
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{f'^2}{2} + \frac{1}{3}af^3 + \frac{1}{2}bf^2+cf\right] = 0
$$
or 
$$
\frac{f'^2}{2} + \frac{1}{3}af^3 + \frac{1}{2}bf^2+cf = \text{Constant} = \lambda
$$
then we have a separable equation
$$
\dfrac{df}{dx} = \pm \sqrt{\lambda -\left(\frac{1}{3}af^3 + \frac{1}{2}bf^2+cf \right)}
$$
now to solve this (maybe) heinous equation..we require the $f(x)$ to play nice ;).

Comment: I don't see what to do after multiplying by $f'$. Is it equivalent to the method proposed here? (section : Equations with the x missing ) http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/nonlineareq/nonlineareq.html
.
If yes I tried this already but the form I get is not solvable. However, I don't attempt to solve it exactly, but I rather try to see what is the influence of the non linear term.

Comment: not really David..but i will edit now. Hopefully it will be clearer :).

Comment: Thank you for your time Chinmy. This is the same result as in what I mentioned. Now we are stuck because $\int \frac{df}{\sqrt{f^3+f^2+...}}$ cant be solved. I am looking for $f(x)$, so why "we require the f(x) to play nice?"

Comment: sorry David..I meant to imply if we could solve it analytically..which probably requires elliptic integrals.

Comment: Analytic solution is indeed very... awful (according to Wolfram), that's why I only wanted to study the non linear effect for small $a$.
Thank you for your time again.